# Gauss lemma for a complete Noetherian domain

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, deformation-theory, galois-representations

Suppose that $R$ is a Noetherian complete domain over a field $K$.

Suppose that a monic polynomial $f(X) \in R[X]$ (i.e., the highest degree $X^e$ in $f$ has the coefficient $1$), satisfies the following two conditions$\colon$

1. $R[X]/(f(X))$ is *not* integral.
2. $f(X) = g(X)^l$ in $F(R)[X]$ for some integer $l > 1$, where $g(X)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $F(R)[X]$ and $F(R)$ is the fractional field of $R$.

### Q. Then, does the following equality hold for some $G(X) \in R[X]$$\colon$ \begin{equation*}
f(X) = G(X)^l~?
\end{equation*}

Comment: Yes if $R$ is integrally closed: then $R[X]$ is integrally closed, and $g$ is clearly integral over $R[X]$.

Comment: No in general in char. $p>0$: take for $R\subset K[[t]]$ the subring of power series without term of degree 1. Then $f=X^p-t^p$ is a counterexample, with $g=X-t$ and $l=p$.